# ReverseProxy with Apache/Tomcat Multiple DNS, single webapp with SSL

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, configuration, reverse-proxy

I am pretty much a newbie at setting up servers and am running into a problem. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS and have Apache2 and Tomcat7 installed. I am using LetsEncrypt and Certbot for SSL. I have a single webapp that I deploy as ROOT.war. This webapp serves 2 distinct groups of users and I have implemented a "multi-site" solution that checks the incoming DNS and filters the data accordingly (along with UI changes). So I have www.sitea.com and www.siteb.com both pointing to localhost. Here is my 000-default.comf

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.sitea.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.sitea.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteb.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.siteb.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And my 000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitea.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitea.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerName www.sitea.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.siteb.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.siteb.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerName www.siteb.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So, for the initial configuration I used Certbot's Apache plugin to configure SSL for sitea (siteb was in production on a different server). This seems to work fine. Now when I change the A record to point the DNS of siteb to the new server I get a 503 from Apache. I did go back and use Certbot to get 2 certificates, one for each DNS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on the answer, needed to add ServerAlias and all is working well.

So

```
ServerName sitea.com
ServerAlias www.sitea.com
```